# Trigger event on webpack element

Tags: jquery, angular, webpack, woocommerce

I am using the OpenPOS plugin on a WordPress/Woocommerce site. Server-side I can grab all kinds of hooks an do fancy stuff. The front-end is js through angular (I think) and webpack. I am familiar with js/jq but not with angular/webpack. I want to trigger a change event on an input element so that the js-code does what it does when I enter a value manually. Should be easy... I thought.

- jQuery('#myelement').trigger('change') is not working.
- window.dispatchEvent(...) is not working.
- document.getElementById('myelement') is not working.

I have meanwhile learned that webpack creates some sort of extra DOM (although all the ins and outs are beyond me), which apparently makes that the things I tried are of no use.

Question: how can I trigger the event?

Here's the element:

```
<input _ngcontent-c1="" autocomplete="off" class="form-control mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-star-inserted ng-dirty ng-touched ng-valid" formcontrolname="barcode" id="scan-barcode-input" matinput="" required="" type="text" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="mat-autocomplete-0" placeholder="Enter product name or id" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true">
```

and this is the beginning of `main.js` which makes me think it's webpack:

```
(window.webpackJsonp = window.webpackJsonp || []).push([[1], {
    "+1n9": function(e, n, t) {
        "use strict";
        Object.defineProperty(n, "__esModule", {
            value: !0
        }),
        n.default = function() {
```

Comment: hi,

Any luck on this ?

Comment: Partly. For this input element I only needed the input that is entered (by a person or through a barcode scan), which I managed to do by adding an event listener on keydown. However, I also want to programmatically change input on a few other input elements and I haven't been able to do so. I tried raising a click event on the input and then dispatch Keyboard events with text, but manually firing doesn't work for security reasons (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent). ng.probe(element) doesnt work because of the prod environment. Still struggling!